# Placing a icon at the bottom of a flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have a screen where I have used three View in flex direction and inside the last view I want to show an icon at the bottom of the view but I was unable to place it . The Ui for the las flex is like this.

```
<Block flex={0.15}>
            <FontAwesome
              flexDirection="column-reverse"
              name="trash-o"
              style={{
                fontSize: 20,
                color: "#777",
                backgroundColor: "#eee",
                //marginTop: 65,
                marginRight: 5,
                //alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
                alignItems: "flex-end"
              }}
            />
          </Block>
```

Here block is nothing but a view component.

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: can you share your code in an expo snack so that we can check and ervert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this once ,

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1 , justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
       <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',flex:0.15}}>
       </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',flex:0.15}}>
       </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'green',flex:0.15, justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
        <Text style={{alignSelf:'center' , flexDirection:'column-reverse'}}>HI there</Text>
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In place of icon im using a text box to align itself  in the bottom

It looks like this [image]

Do go through code once, if you dont understand ill explain you.

Hop irt helps .feel free for doubts